# Dynamically highlighting text when the text to highlight is within a <span> tag embedded inside an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a task to highlight text on a page when clicking a link from a separate page component that when the link is clicked from the separate component it will jump to and highlight the text within the target id.  In my case the text I want to target to highlight is embedded within:

```
<a id='dynamically_generated_id'><span class='dynamic_class_name'>{text_to_highlight}</span></a>
```

When clicking on a link:

```
<a href={dynamically_generated_id}>
```

The text embedded in the span tag should highlight.  How do I create my CSS file to handle this?  I've tried:

```
a {
   & span:target {
     background-color: #ffa;
     }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  I'm rusty with CSS so any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe you are using scss. If so then try removing the & operator before span i think it should be `a{span:target{background-color: black}}`

Comment: Id is set on the a not the span. `&:target span` should be your selector.

Comment: Thanks for both responses.  G-Cyrillus, your solution did work to highlight the text.